# Scala and Java Generics -- Extracting and returning nested types

Tags: java, scala, generics, stanford-nlp, scala-java-interop

Java generics can infer the type of generic type parameters based on the return type of expressions. Consider the following:

```
public static <T> T uncheckedCast(Object o) {
    return (T)o;
}
```

We can call it such as:

```
Map<Baz,Bog> bazbogMap = new HashMap<Baz,Bog>();
String foo = uncheckedCast(bazbogMap);
```

This will compile but throw a `RuntimeException` when it is invoked, as it will try to cast the `Map` to a `String` but fail. But the point is that Java inferred the value of `<T>` based on the expected resultant type at the callsite.

We can also do this in Scala with:

```
def uncheckedCast[T](o: AnyRef): T = o.asInstanceOf[T]
```

So far, so good.

Java can also infer type arguments from nested definitions and return those (i.e. we do not actually have to assign the result to a type to use it as above before using it; Java knows what it is already.)

A simple class showing this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class KeysAndValues {
    public interface Key<T> {}
    public static class StringKey implements Key<String> {}

    private final Map<Class<?>, Object> lookup;

    public KeysAndValues() {
        lookup = new HashMap<Class<?>, Object>();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <V, K extends Key<V>> V put(Class<K> key, V value) {
        return (V) lookup.put(key, value);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <V, K extends Key<V>> V get(Class<K> key) {
        return (V) lookup.get(key);
    }

    public static void test() {
        KeysAndValues kv = new KeysAndValues();
        kv.put(StringKey.class, "BAM!"); // returns null
        kv.put(StringKey.class, "BOOM!"); // returns "BAM!"
        kv.get(StringKey.class); // returns "BOOM!"
    }
}
```

However, in Scala this class causes problems. The REPL:

```
scala> val kv = new KeysAndValues
kv: KeysAndValues = KeysAndValues@13c2982e

scala> import KeysAndValues.StringKey
import KeysAndValues.StringKey

scala> kv.put(classOf[StringKey], "BAM!")
res0: java.lang.String = null

scala> kv.put(classOf[StringKey], "BOOM!")
res1: java.lang.String = BAM!

scala> kv.get(classOf[StringKey])
<console>:10: error: inferred type arguments [Nothing,KeysAndValues.StringKey] do not conform to method get's type parameter bounds [V,K <: KeysAndValues.Key[V]]
              kv.get(classOf[StringKey])
```

The two calls to `put()` specify a value for the `V` type parameter which allows them to work, but as soon as the `V` parameter needs to be extracted from the inheritance of the `K` parameter, things break down. The Java code has no such issue.

The only way to get Scala not to complain is to explicitly define the types:

```
kv.get[String, StringKey](classOf[StringKey])
```

(For something simple and contrived like the above it's marginally alright (violates DRY), but for something more involved, like The Stanford Core NLP API, where you have to do something like:

```
doc.get[java.util.Map[Integer, CorefChain], CorefChainAnnotation](classOf[CorefChainAnnotation])
```

Which includes manually looking up the nested types so you can add them, is quite a pain.)

**The Question(s):**

Is there a way to get this to work without having to specify the type parameters so verbosely? More importantly, why is this a problem to begin with? How is Java able to infer the type argument when Scala is not?

**EDIT 1**: Removed most of the code demonstrating the Stanford Core NLP problem and replaced it with a general example of the difference in Scala/Java generics that exemplifies the issue.

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in compilable plain Java and Scala code, without external libraries?

Comment: Probably. Let me take a crack at it.

Comment: Added a Java class and REPL output showing the difference.

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell you exactly why Scala can't infer the Java type parameters, but I can at least show you how to declare the type parameters in Java so that Scala *can* infer them:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <V> V put(Class<? extends Key<V>> key, V value) {
    return (V) lookup.put(key, value);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <V> V get(Class<? extends Key<V>> key) {
    return (V) lookup.get(key);
}
```

I think the key point here is that you don't *need* that `K` type parameter at all - a wildcarded type parameter, `? extends Key<V>` will give you the same functionality. This then works happily from Scala without having to specify any type parameters:

```
scala> kv.put(classOf[StringKey], "BAM!")
res0: String = null

scala> kv.get(classOf[StringKey])
res1: String = BAM!
```

**EDIT:**

Here's the best I could do for a workaround. It requires higher-kinded types and a cast. Not sure that I can explain why this compiles but the other version doesn't though. ;-)

```
scala> import KeysAndValues._
import KeysAndValues._

scala> import scala.language.higherKinds
import scala.language.higherKinds

scala> def get[V, K[X] <: Key[X]](kv: KeysAndValues, key: Class[_ <: K[V]]) =
     |   kv.get[V, K[V]](key.asInstanceOf[Class[K[V]]])
get: [V, K[X] <: KeysAndValues.Key[X]](kv: KeysAndValues, key: Class[_ <: K[V]])V

scala> val kv = new KeysAndValues
kv: KeysAndValues = KeysAndValues@24c63dac

scala> kv.put(classOf[StringKey], "BAM!")
res0: String = null

scala> get(kv, classOf[StringKey])
res1: String = BAM!
```

Comment: This is a good partial answer. My example was taken from Stanford Core NLP, where I cannot edit the source. I would still like to know if there is another Scala only workaround (unlikely?) and why this difference exists between Scala/Java.

Comment: I contacted the Stanford Core NLP folks about this issue, and I believe that as of Stanford Core NLP 1.3.5, they now use the simpler generics I proposed at the beginning of my answer. So you might try upgrading to Stanford Core NLP 1.3.5 and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: That's great news from a usability standpoint; I would still really like to know why Java and Scala have this difference though.